# CSS table-like presentation with intervening wrappers?

Tags: html, css

I have a complicated entry form, fully functional, which I need to style. The developers used multiple wrapping divs and there is lots of JavaScript depending on them. I just cannot get rid of them or restructure without delving deep into the logic, and this is not possible with the current deadline. But for UX reasons, I cannot visually structure the page in the same way that the divs are structured.

Because I didn't want to wrap real table rows in divs (I don't even know if this is possible!), I went with divs set to display as table rows, table cells, etc. So this is what I have now.

```
<div class="mock-table">
<div id="names">
    <div class="mock-tr">
        <div class="mock-td  label-column">
            <label>Full name *</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mock-td field-column">
            <input type="text" id="fullNameEntry" />
        </div>
        <div class="mock-td hints-column">
            <div class="hints">Please use international nomenclature for naming strains</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mock-tr">
        <div class="mock-td  label-column">
            <label>Short name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mock-td field-column">
            <input type="text" id="shortNameEntry" />
        </div>
        <div class="mock-td hints-column"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="backgroundInfo">
    <legend></legend>
    <div class="mock-tr">
        <div class="mock-td  label-column">
            <label>Phenotype</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mock-td field-column">
            <textarea id="phenotype" ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="mock-td hints-column"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is really important that the two names have a common wrapper, and that the phenotype is not in the same wrapper! Our functionality depends on that. And yes, I know that tables were not meant to display such a structure, but this is what I get to work with.

But as you can see on the [rendering](http://jsfiddle.net/RFKrL/), I get a problem with display widths. When there is a column in a wrapper such that no single row has enough width to fill the mock table cell, the whole mock-tr gets a much lower width than it should have. This is what happens with the phenotype in my example. So the mock-table div has its 100%, and the id="phenotype" div has its actual 100%, but the mock-tr div nested inside is only as wide as its content, despite being explicitly set to 100%.

I found an ugly hack to work around that, by inserting a div into each mock cell, and filling its ::after with a very long text, color set to invisible and only 1 pixel high. But there must be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: your `mock-tr`s need to be a direct child of the `mock-tables` and you shouldn't have another children under the table - treat them like real `table` and `tr` elements if you are using display table properties.  I also usually give the table a width - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/RFKrL/2/

Comment: @Pete this is exactly why I asked the question: They cannot be direct children. There is lots of functionality depending on them not being direct children. This is the one part of the structure which I cannot change. I have the structure (which is not really a table) to display as if it were a table.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that bit about the direct children, you could try using floats then - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/RFKrL/4/

Comment: @Pete I tried just floating the columns as in typical multi-column design, but there was some problem in aligning the "cells" horizontally with each other. I'll try playing with it a bit more.

Comment: I noticed that you class names in the styling css didn't match your classes on the divs for the `label-column` and `field-column` (your css in the original fiddle seemed to have an extra s on them), this could have caused your horizontal alignment issues?